# Configured SSH settings on Ubuntu to connect remotely from local Windows 10 OS, for VSCODE. Could I get some verification on the settings I changed?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I had a ton of trouble configuring SSH connection via remote from VSCODE on windows to my Ubuntu server. I managed to solve the issue by editing/uncommenting the following:

`sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I'm not so sure how secure my SSH is now, could I get some feedback from the above? Setting aside typical SSH security know-abouts, would changing the settings above compromise me even further?

Comment: Do you have a key for PubKeyAuthentication?

Comment: @user535733 Yes, i have a public key

Comment: PermitRootLogin should be by key auth only, NOT with password auth.  So `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` is the way you should go, forcing the use of the authorized keys file and SSH key only

Comment: @ThomasWard Thank you for pointing that out, just changed it! That seems to be the only major concern from the settings?

Comment: If you have a PubKey, and you can reliably login with it, then disable password use: `PasswordAuthentication no`. Many passwords are easy to guess or brute-force.

Comment: @user535733 thank you so much for the recommendation. Just implemented your great suggestion.